# Cygwin: Unable to use termios

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

I'm running the following in Eclipse using the Cygwin as the toolchain and the error code is executing. I get:

> cannot get params about stdin: Inappropriate ioctl for device

It's fine in Linux.  I've been able to run other code that doesn't use this header.  Also, how can I set up Eclipse to debug code that is in Cygwin itself or in a remote Linux server?

```
#include    <termios.h>

  struct termios ttyinfo; /* this struct holds tty info */

      if (tcgetattr(0, &ttyinfo) == -1) { /* get info */
          perror("cannot get params about stdin");
          exit(1);
      }
```

Comment: Did you try including `<sys/termios.h>`?

Comment: Yes I got the same error message.